# React-share: How to pass image as thumbnail?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-share

In my project, the react-share package is used for the share button functionality. I would like to send an image as a thumbnail along with the URL, but how can I make it happen?

```
<FacebookShareButton
    url={openShare.link}
    onClick={() => handleClose() }
>

    <FacebookIcon size={40} round={true} />
</FacebookShareButton>

<WhatsappShareButton
    url={openShare.link}
    onClick={() => handleClose()}
>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
import { FacebookShareButton, WhatsappShareButton } from 'react-share';

const shareUrl = openShare.link; // Replace with your actual URL
const imageUrl = 'https://example.com/path/to/image.jpg'; // Replace with the URL of your image

<FacebookShareButton
  url={shareUrl}
  onClick={() => handleClose()}
  quote="Check out this awesome website!"
  hashtag="#react"
  image={imageUrl} // Add the image URL here
>
  <FacebookIcon size={40} round={true} />
</FacebookShareButton>

<WhatsappShareButton
  url={shareUrl}
  onClick={() => handleClose()}
>
 {/* Add your custom WhatsApp button */}
</WhatsappShareButton>
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76456219/edit), not here in comments (*** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written right now).

Comment: Stack Snippets are not for general formatting. Does it actually run?

Comment: image is not a valid prop in react-share

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).